# vba-excel click event triggered during initialize when load data into a text box

Tags: excel, vba

I am using VBA Excel.  I am formatting data from several sources to display in a text box (as a quick summary), when the user clicks on this text box I have another userform that will display to edit this data. When I move the data into the text box during initialize the click event triggers.  Is there a way to turn off the event during initialize then turn it back on? This does not happen if I have the user do the double click, however I would like it to be a single click if possible for consistency with the rest of the maintenance screens.

Comment: There's no built-in way to disable events on UserForms. YOu will need to set a Public (or otherwise appropriately) scoped variable and use that within the event procedure to `Exit Sub` conditionally.

Comment: `When I move the data into the text box during initialize the click event triggers` You mean move data from the other *UserForm* into the textbox? That shouldn't trigger the click event but the change event instead. Are you sure you have no *Change Event* in the code?

Comment: I call a module where I format the data for the textbox, then move the data into the textbox with "Me.Controls("textbox1").Value = TmpData .  At this point during the initialization subroutine the textbox1_click subroutine is called. Since this is a summary of data I don't allow the user to change the textbox, so I have no change events defined.  Thanks for the exit sub answer, this will work for my purposes.  I had not seen exit sub before. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If the click event triggers then you must be using the wrong event make sure that the event handler does not look like this `TextBox1_Change()` if so change the event to `DblClick`

Comment: I was trying to use the single click because it matches the handling on the rest of the screens.  This system is for people who older and not very computer literate, so the more consistent the better.  The other answer I received was to exit sub conditionally.  This will work very well for my purposes. Since this box summarizes data I do not allow editing so I did not create a change subroutine.  Thanks for taking the time to answer my question.  Double click did work, but my tester was confused by this.